# DbUpdateConcurrencyException was unhandled by user code fix

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

"An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."

Hi I get this error when trying to edit the orders in my system. Creating and Deleting orders works fine its is only while trying to edit an order I receive this error.

I have a brief idea of why the error is caused but cant seem to fix it.

code from system follows

Edit method

```
   // POST: Orders/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(CustomerOrder order)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(order);
        }
```

the model

```
[Bind(Exclude = "Id")]
    public class CustomerOrder
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
        [StringLength(70)]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postal Code is required")]
        [DisplayName("Postal Code")]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone is required")]
        [StringLength(24)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required")]
        [DisplayName("Email Address")]

        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",
            ErrorMessage = "Email is is not valid.")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public Decimal Amount { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string CustomerUserName { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public List<OrderedProduct> Products { get; set; }

        public string ToString(CustomerOrder order)
        {
            StringBuilder bob = new StringBuilder();

            bob.Append("<p>Order Information for Order: " + order.Id + "<br>Placed at: " + order.DateCreated + "</p>").AppendLine();
            bob.Append("<p>Name: " + order.FirstName + " " + order.LastName + "<br>");
            bob.Append("Address: " + order.Address + " " + order.City + " " + order.State + " " + order.PostalCode + "<br>");
            bob.Append("Contact: " + order.Email + "     " + order.Phone + "</p>");

            bob.Append("<br>").AppendLine();
            bob.Append("<Table>").AppendLine();
            // Display header 
            string header = "<tr> <th>Item Name</th>" + "<th>Quantity</th>" + "<th>Price</th> <th></th> </tr>";
            bob.Append(header).AppendLine();

            String output = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in order.Products)
                {
                    bob.Append("<tr>");
                    output = "<td>" + item.Product.Name + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.Quantity + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.Quantity * item.Product.Price + "</td>";
                    bob.Append(output).AppendLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(output);
                    bob.Append("</tr>");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                output = "No items ordered.";
            }
            bob.Append("</Table>");
            bob.Append("<b>");
            // Display footer 
            string footer = String.Format("{0,-12}{1,12}\n",
                                          "Total", order.Total);
            bob.Append(footer).AppendLine();
            bob.Append("</b>");

            return bob.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

the edit view

```
@model bob.Models.CustomerOrder
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <h4>Order</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostalCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostalCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Any help would be great as I am close to finishing this website and will be really happy when it is done.

Comment: `[Bind(Exclude = "Id")]` excludes the `Id` property from binding so its always `0` and you try to save a `CustomerOrder` with `id=0` which does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bind(Exclude = "Id")] in the customerOrder class is causing your problem.remove and try it.give me feedback if it works